# Run a JasperServer report via PHP and pass over the querystring

Tags: php, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using Web Services to run some reports created in iReport on JasperReports Server.  Inside the .jrxml file I can see the `<querystring>` xml that holds the SQL for the report.  Is it possible to pass this querystring over to JasperServer via Web Services, instead of hard coding the definition inside the .jrxml file.  This is the string I would build in PHP, then pass over to JasperReports Server to be used in the execution of the report.

```
<queryString>
   <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM table WHERE j=2]]>
</queryString>
```

Basically, I'm trying to find a way to dynamically create the SQL in PHP, then pass the SQL over to Jasper to run the report. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out I could do this by setting up a parameter with $P!{query} instead of using $P{query}.  The "!" makes the difference.  Hope it helps someone else who comes along with the same problem.